# No results view filtering on newly added field of content type

Tags: 7, views

I have a content type called Parts. I just added a new boolean field called `is_accessory` with the default value being false. I added a filter on an existing view to show only Parts where `is_accessory` is false. When I run the view, no parts show up.

If I go to a Part page, select edit, then select save (without changing anything) that part will show up.

Do I need to write a [hook_update_N](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_update_N/7.x) function that loads and saves all the Part records?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the views filter operation to `Is not equal to` and the value as `true`.

This should work for new entities that have the value as `false` and old entities where it just isn't set.